# error when importing list _catalogs/fpdatasources

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, import

I'm pretty new to Sharepoint. I am importing (with Import-SPWeb) the lists of a Sharepoint 2010 site into a 2013 server.

While the process completes without problems in other lists with _catalogs/fpdatasources
I get the following error:

```
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] Start Time: 1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM.
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] Progress: Initializing Import.
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] Warning: Export only contains the last major of a file.
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] Progress: Starting content import.
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] Progress: De-Serializing Objects to Database.
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] [Folder] [fpdatasources] Progress: Importing
[1/9/2014 3:10:44 PM] [Folder] [fpdatasources]   Verbose: Source URL: _catalogs/fpdatasources
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [Folder] [fpdatasources]   ExtendedVerbose: Creating
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [Folder] [Forms] Progress: Importing
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [Folder] [Forms]   Verbose: Source URL: _catalogs/fpdatasources/Forms
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [Folder] [Forms]   ExtendedVerbose: Creating
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [List] [fpdatasources] Progress: Importing
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] [List] [fpdatasources]   ExtendedVerbose: Creating
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] ExtendedVerbose: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Resources_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Resources'. The duplicate key value is (8875c48f-699d-4b37-8038-fbfd1f32a47c, dc557ddf-d204-47d7-9b1c-25ad16d31dfc, e718af54-b40a-4706-8ec4-2942db2a8773, _ListTitle, 1040).
The statement has been terminated.
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Debug:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource.AddInternal()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ResourceSerializer.AddUserResource(SPUserResourceCollection userResources, XmlElement resourceData, SPImportSettings settings)
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Verbose: Performing final fixups.
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Progress: Import completed.
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Finish Time: 1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM.
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Duration: 00:00:01
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Total Objects: 4
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Finished with 1 warnings.
[1/9/2014 3:10:45 PM] Finished with 0 errors.
```

Could you please tell me how to sort this problem out?
And what is this list about?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is my Powershell script to export code

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity '$sourceUrl' -Path $filecmp -ItemUrl $urllist -nofilecompression -Verbose
```

Here is my import code:

```
Import-SPWeb "http://myNewIntranet/mysubsite"  -path $_.FullName -Force -Verbose -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

Comment: Do you have custom content type? 
Do you have custom site column?
Did you enable versioning?

Comment: also make sure, the list template should be same on both source and target....having same content type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh you are exporting a SharePoint 2010 List and then importing into SharePoint 2013...correct?
this is not supported, you have to upgrade the content DB from 2010 to 2013.
here are the steps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2012/07/17/upgrading-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step.aspx

Comment: Yes correct. Anyway,I see the lists I use are imported correctly. Only the one I mentioned has problems but I still have to understand what that list is.

Comment: here is fool proper way to import from 2010 to 2013( 3 Methods.)  3 ways http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html 
I bet it will give you error and will not work because that is resource list which required to work properly

Comment: Well, that is exactly the link I used. Precisely I used method 1. I exported and imported the list singly.  Only that fpdatasources , that appears as a system list doesn't work.

Comment: are you importing a single list or subsite?

Comment: All the lists of a subsite.I do it 1 by 1 but with  PowerShell script

Comment: can you share your import & export command, also are you creating list at destination server before the import command.

Comment: #Waqas Sarwar MCSE I added the scripts. I hadn't created any list before importing. Indeed, the subsite was empty.

Comment: what template you are using for subsite when creating it?....try to create a blank subsite and then try to import....here is powershell way...withoutmentioning any template.
New-SPWeb –url http://sp2010/PSSubSite -name "PS Sub Site"
–AddToTopNav -UseParentTopNav

Comment: Creating the subsite with New-SPWeb gave no problems. But I e only now I see from a log that a fresh subsite created yesterday from the browser yesterday worked fine also. Thanks for you time.